# flash-player and cross domain socket connections

Tags: cross-domain, flash, cross-domain-policy

i have a flash game hosted on domain a.com which connects using sockets to a game server on domain b.com on a certain port other than 80.
now this doesnt work. the connection cant be established and i assume this is because of cross-domain security in flash-player.

now i have read that this problem can be solved with a crossdomain.xml file. but i dont quite understand where i have to put this? on domain a or domain b?
domain b doesnt even have port 80 open since that game server is listening on a custom port.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll direct you to the official documentation. If you still have any doubts, please just let me know and I'll do my best to answer them. From your question, you want to know where the crossdomain file is hosted, the basic setting is that it should be hosted on the source domain, that is domain a, in the base of the host (a.com/crossdomain.xml).

Here's the base documentation file:
http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/download/attachments/64389123/CrossDomain_PolicyFile_Specification.pdf?version=1

A few specific guides that should help you:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/cross_domain_policy.html
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html

Comment: thanks but it turned out it needs to be on domain b. that is the remote domain where the gameserver is running.

Comment: Wait, this is very confusing. So the swf is being hosted on a.com, but the crossdomain is on b.com? Doesn't make any sense. Only a.com should have the control over what can get accessed for security reasons.

Comment: yes, that is what it is like now and it is now indeed working. i had to open port 80 for this on domain b.com and put crossdomain.xml in the root directory.